# MySQL: displayed all rows from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to display all rows from 3 tables.

I need to display the complete customer list.
Each customer can have 0, 1 or more submissions.
Each submission can have 0,1 or more products.

```
CustomerID | submissionID | submissionProductID
001        | s001         | sp001 
001        | s002         | sp002 
002        | s003         | sp003     
002        | s003         | sp004      
002        | s003         | sp005 
003        | ---          | ---
004        | s005         | ---
```

so:

```
customer 1 has 2 submissions, 1 product in each.
customer 2 has 1 submission containing 3 products.
customer 3 has no submission.
customer 4 has 1 submission but no pruducts.
```

I can't seem to display ALL records.
The SQL below will display all the customers, but not multiple submisison rows, or multiple product rows.

And of course, some customer will have a blank submission and product.
And some customer submissions will not have a product.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID as 'CustID', s.submissionID, sp.submissionProductID
FROM tblCustomer c
LEFT JOIN tblSubmission s on c.CustomerID = s.customerID
LEFT JOIN tblSubmissionProducts sp on s.submissionID  = sp.submissionID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: remove your group by clause, don't use it if you don't have aggregate function which requires a group by clause.

Comment: That did the trick i think. Just testing the output again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get all records, please try this;)

```
SELECT c.CustomerID as 'CustID', s.submissionID, sp.submissionProductID
FROM tblCustomer c
LEFT JOIN tblSubmission s on c.CustomerID = s.customerID
LEFT JOIN tblSubmissionProducts sp on s.submissionID  = sp.submissionID
ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Yeah. that works. 
I had tried that before but it didn't work. Not sure why. Working now.
Thanks Dr Stitch  and Reno.